# Ansible ranges of hosts and host_vars

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have an inventory like this:

```
master:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_user: ubuntu
      ip: localhost
workers:
  hosts:
    worker-[0:1]:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_user: ubuntu
```

And now I want to define some variables using vars files that do apply to all workers in the `worker-[0:1]`. My first intuition was creating `host_vars/worker-[0:1].yml` but this fails as the variables set in the `.yml` are apparently not read.

Is there a way to do this without creating one file for every entry in the range or creating a group for every range defined and then using group vars?

Comment: If you want to define the same set of vars with the same values for a bunch of machines (wither you define them with a range or not) place them in a group and define the vars for the group. If you want to define the vars for each host, create one file for each host.

Comment: Note that you can eventually set those vars directly in the inventory file for the host range as demonstrated in your above example for e.g. `ansible_connection`. But there is no way to match a file defined after the range definition inside a `host_vars` directory as you found out.

Comment: @zeitounator can you make this an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: Isn't the answer from Salim saying approximately the same thing? Edit the answer to add the precision you find useful and accept it.

Comment: I am not comfortable doing this as the only two things that do answer my question are I) the inventory file solution II) That indeed no other solution exists without creating one file for every entry or creating a group for every range defined and then using group vars. Both "solution" they offered were already explicitly excluded.